# Are there locales or common programs that use YYYY-DD-MM as the date format?

Tags: datetime, localization, locale

I've often standardized on `YYYY-MM-DD` as the date format for communicating within a geographically distributed project teams to dispel any ambiguity that might arise from local date formats.

Is it likely that I might run into people who are used to seeing dates as `YYYY-DD-MM`? Are there programs that use this as a date format?

Comment: Ummm... Every program that uses the OS locale correctly can use dates like this.  The number of programs that *don't* use locale correctly is probably a shorter list.  What are you really asking?

Comment: He's asking if somebody can be expected to interpret YYYY-MM-DD incorrectly for the ambiguous cases, like 2010-02-11

Comment: Vinko is correct in his interpretation of my question. I marked an answer based on the link to see what date format is used for different locales.

Comment: I prefer YYYY-mm-dd (ISO8601) because it seems likely to be unambiguous. I came to this question to verify that it is, indeed, unambiguous.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See "[Calendar date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#List_of_the_world_locations_by_date_format_in_use)" on Wikipedia on the topic - it lists the countries by date/time format.

At first glance it doesn't look like anyone is using `YYYY-DD-MM` regularly.

Answer (score 5):

`yyyy-mm-dd` in particular is a subset of the ISO-8601 format.

There is no recognised standard that uses `year date month`.  When `year` is first, it should always be followed by an appropriate sub-year, be that quarter, month, julian day, etc.

Some advantages to using year-first is that the order also happens to work well for alpha-sorting when used as a text value (such as part of a file name).

Answer (score 4):

You should try to get your team(s) to standardize on [ISO 8601](https://web.archive.org/web/20161129195230/http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/iso8601) formatting, or use it and tell everyone that's what you're using.  Or see Wikipedia's [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) reference.

Comment: [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) has become a better reference for the small subset of ISO 8601 that programmers use.  ISO includes weirder options like 2022-W37-4, 2022-258, decimal fractions of _minutes_ etc...  The ISO text is long & behind a paywall, while the RFC is short and public.

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia **Kazakhstan** may use `YYYY.DD.MM`. I can't read the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#cite_note-93) for this information, so I don't know the specifics.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

That aside, I do believe that the delimiter still makes it visibly different from `YYYY-MM-DD`, so there should be no issue.

Example: `2017-01-13` vs `2017.13.01`

As also mentioned by [@Tracker1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601638/5815327) and [@DaveE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2254164/5815327), `YYYY-MM-DD` is the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format.

Answer (score 0):

There are none in the list of cultures in Windows that default to YYYY-DD-MM, so I would say you are pretty safe, in general, however since you can customize the dates, you should probably support it, if you want to be sure.