# How to change the format of date in date picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, datepicker, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

In my iPhone app, I need to display date in **`yyyy/MM/dd`** format as show in beloow image

[image]

but in iPhone Date picker it is in the format of **MM/dd/yyyy** which is not in uniform for my application

I tried with changing the local values (with different country regions) of the Date picker but no use it still in the default format.

How can I Change the date format on Date picker as per my requirement?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740423/how-to-display-picker-view-in-mm-dd-yy-format-in-ios-5-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Apple's documentation they specified that in `UIDatePickerModeDate`. The `DatePicker` displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the `locale` setting. An example of this mode is [ November | 15 | 2007 ]. But In device it display as DD/MM/YYYY. See [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) for more info.

So if you want to do it yourself you could create your own `UIPickerView` with the values you want.

Answer (score 5):

The UIDatePicker is made to adapt to the user's settings. Changing its format using the locale: method was possible but is now deprecated in iOS 5.0.

You can view your format in the settings of your iPhone :

```
Settings > General > International > Region Format >
```

If you want a specific format, consider making your own picker but it is very discouraged for a date picker.

And also refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254014/are-there-locales-or-common-programs-that-use-yyyy-dd-mm-as-the-date-format)

Comment: Looks like the `locale` is still available. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/locale  and the settings on iOS 8.4 is now `Settings > General > Language & Region`

Answer (score -1):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *gmtZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmtZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"day, MMM HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *dateT = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str1];
NSString *strDateTaken=[appDelegate convertDate:dateT withFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter release];
- (NSString *)convertDate:(NSDate *)date withFormat:(NSString *)format {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:format];
    NSString *dt = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [formatter release];
    return dt;
}
```