# How To Get UIDatePicker To Display A 3 Letter Month

Tags: swift, ios8, uidatepicker

I am using the UIDatePicker to allow the user of my app the select a date. I have the datePickerMode set for 'date' so it will only display the current date. Is there a way to get the month to display the 3 letter month instead of completely spelling it out? I am seeking to conserve on space.

Comment: I don't think so. You could conceivably build your own using UIPickerView, but I wouldn't really recommend it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952063/how-to-change-the-format-of-date-in-date-picker