# How to change Date Format in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I got stuck that I don't know how to change Date Format in UIDatePicker? As default, current dateformat in UIDatePicker is `December 23 2015`. What I want is I want to change `23 Dec 2015`.

Any solution will be appreciated.

Comment: It's locale specific. You need to create your own picker. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13952239/2710486)

Answer (score 1):

The displayed date format of the UIDatePicker is depending on the locale settings of the UIDatePicker.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/locale

To change it, you have to set an NSLocale, which prefers your format.