# Display Year, Month and Date in sequence on DateTimePicker iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, datepicker, datetimepicker

Here is my situation, Current Date picker is showing date, month and year in sequence of Date, Month and Year OR Month, Date and Year. But I want to display this sequence as Year first then Month and at last Date.

I searched a lot but same question I found in Javascript but not in iOS, I also searched in Apple Documentation but I didn't find any solution.

How can I achieve this sequence Year, Month and Date?  If there any property or method available for DateTime Picker? OR Do I need to use custom picker? if any then which?

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly you should go with custom picker man...:)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13952239/2455122

Answer (score 0):

The order of year, month and day is depending on the picker's locale.
Eg.

```
datePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "zh_TW")
```

will have different order from

```
datePicker.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
```

Comment: This is not the solution I wanted. It will change language of Date Time picker view. I guess Chinese. I need solution with no language change or english would be ok.

Comment: If this is the case, create your own custom datepicker view may be easier.