# How to use daterformatter in datePicker view

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I am using swift2.2 with Xcode 7.3.1.
I want to use date picker with format  **30 AUG 2015**.
My picker is in date mode,how to display picker with this date formatter.I want datePicker like the following image:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the format of date in date picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952063/how-to-change-the-format-of-date-in-date-picker)

Answer (score 0):

this is the stuff you are looking for `dd MMM yyyy` this link may help you http://nsdateformatter.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is an example of code you can use. It shows the date on a label.
All hou have to do is to create your own label and replace "myLabel" or specify myLabel's frame to make it visible.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker! //Picker connected from UI

//Give your picker a function (in viewDidLoad)

    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SettingViewController.datePickerAction), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

//This is the function it shows date on custom label(myLabel)

    func datePickerAction() {

            let myLabel = UILabel() //Declaration of label 
            let myLabelFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            myLabelFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
            myLabel.text = "Date: " +          myLabelFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)

        }
```