# How can I change NSDate to a date string picked from date picker?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

UIDatePicker returns me the date in the form of 15Aug,2016 but my date format should be 15/08/2016 in string format.
Example "dob" = "15/08/2016"
I am using this code

```
let dateFormatter=NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
let strDate=dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date) as String 
dict["dob"] = strDate
```

But I am not getting proper string .

Comment: "UIDatePicker returns me the date in the form of 15Aug,2016" No, it doesn't. It returns you a date, not a string. If you want a string, use a date formatter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the format of date in date picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952063/how-to-change-the-format-of-date-in-date-picker)

Comment: I am using a http post method in which I need to send these parameters .["username"="user1","key"="qwerk12","dob"="15/12/2000].So how can use the dob picked from picker ? Please any code for that because I am new to swift as well as iOS .

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and better explain what issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: I am very much afraid of how to update my question further

Comment: var dateFormatter=NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
varstrDate=dateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDatePicker.date)
self.selectedDate.text=strDate

Comment: Will it help me ?

Comment: What problem are you having? The code you posted will convert the selected date into `15-08-2016`. Other than you specifying dashes (`-`) instead of slashes (`/`), isn't that what you want? What is your issue?

Comment: Yes .got it thak a lot Maddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this

```
let dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
let dob = dateformatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

the dob in 15/08/2016 format

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like these:

```
var fecha = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
var fechaNac = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(fecha)
```

You can actually play whit many formats like yyyy-MM-dd, you can get a good explanation here:

http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/