# Is it possible to change a UIDatePicker to start with Year, Month and Day?

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

Is it possible to change a UIDatePicker to start with Year, Month and Day? I looked at many possible scenarios and i cant get to a conclusion.

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **NO**, you can't with the UIDatePicker.

You have to build custom for that.

[Here you will find many.](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=datepicker) Choose the one that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can change.In storyboard -> attribute inspector -> change Mode as Date.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952063/how-to-change-the-format-of-date-in-date-picker)