# How to add datepickerview on IQKeyboardManagerSwift in swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I am new in Swift and I am facing problem to show datepickerview on IQKeyboardManagerSwift

I am trying code like this but it is not working

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.dischargeDateTextField = textField

    // Create a date picker for the date field.
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateDateField(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    // If the date field has focus, display a date picker instead of keyboard.
    // Set the text to the date currently displayed by the picker.
    textField.inputView = picker
    textField.text = formatDateForDisplay(date: picker.date)
}

// Called when the date picker changes.

@objc func updateDateField(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    dischargeDateTextField?.text = formatDateForDisplay(date: sender.date)
}


// Formats the date chosen with the date picker.

fileprivate func formatDateForDisplay(date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

I need date format in "yyyy-mm-dd" but it only shows as in image

[image]

I change code like this

```
 fileprivate func formatDateForDisplaySurgery(date: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyy-mm-dd"
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
```

but it nor working

Comment: It's locale specific. Kindly refer this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952239/3825016

Comment: The code which you have updated in formatDateForDisplaySurgery method will only reflect in your textField display. It will not change datepicker display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your code of inputView in `viewDidLoad()` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateDateField(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    // If the date field has focus, display a date picker instead of keyboard.
    // Set the text to the date currently displayed by the picker.
    self.dischargeDateTextField.inputView = picker
}
```

and remove that same lines of code from `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method.

The other methods have been correctly written by you.

```
@objc func updateDateField(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    dischargeDateTextField?.text = formatDateForDisplay(date: sender.date)
}

// Formats the date chosen with the date picker.
fileprivate func formatDateForDisplay(date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: @Muju It's locale specific. Kindly refer this link, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952239/3825016

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in 'viewDidLoad' method.

```
let picker = UIDatePicker()
picker.datePickerMode = .date
picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateDateField(sender:)), for: 
.valueChanged)
self.dischargeDateTextField .inputView = picker
```

Answer (score 0):

First initialize your datePicker,

```
var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
```

Add this code your `viewDidLoad` instead of `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    dateTxtF.inputView = datePicker /// Set InputView to textfield

}
```

The `dateChanged` method

```
    @objc func dateChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
        print(sender.date.year)
        print(sender.date.month)
        print(sender.date.day)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension for the `UITextField` which will help you to get the DatePicker for any of your UITextField

```
func addDatePicker(target: Any, selector: Selector) {
    //Add DatePicker as inputView
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .valueChanged)
    self.inputView = datePicker
}
```

Handle the action method of the date picker

```
@objc func updatedDate(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    print(sender.date)
}
```

once you create and above extension you can use that with your textfield like this

```
YOUR_TXTFLD.addDatePicker(target: self, selector: #selector(updatedDate(sender:)))
```