# SQL Query using two dates

Tags: sql, excel, vba, oracle, date

I can run the below SQL query when it contains a single date. When I introduce a second date no results are returned.

I also got this to work using the `DD/MM/YY` format, but only with one date.

I am using Office 2010 and connecting to an Oracle SQL database.

```vb
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
   
ConnectionString = SQLConnect 'This is a function that resolves to the connection string
cnn.Open ConnectionString
cnn.CommandTimeout = 180
    
StrQuery = "select  ref, date from records  where  date > '10-MAY-20'  And date < '13-MAY-20'"
    
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
cnn.Close
```

I tried amending the query to "select  noteno, trandate from records  where  date between '10-MAY-20'  And '13-MAY-20'".

Both queries work in Oracle SQL Developer when a single date is used.

The "select  noteno, trandate from records  where  date like '%MAY-20'" also doesn't work when run via VBA (but fine in Oracle SQL developer).

Comment: The date cannot be less than `10-MAY-20`  and at the same time more than `13-MAY-20` if you need the dates in between then switch your `<` and `>` signs. If you mean all the dates that are **not** in between then your `And` needs to be an `Or`. • Also make sure your date has the correct format you migh need to change it to `2020-05-10` (depends on your setup, check it).

Comment: Thank you - sorry i had retyped the <> symbols in a hurry this morning and got them back to front, they are correct in the VBA. Could you please confirm if the date format you have suggested if YYYY-MM-DD (UK) or YYYY-DD-MM (US) please?

Comment: `DATE` doesn't have any format, it's the locale-specific `NLS settings` which have format to display the date in string. `'10-MAY-20'` is NOT a date, it is a string. You must use `TO_DATE` to convert it into date. Or, use the `ANSI date literal`. Also, stop using the **two-digit** representation for **year**. It's the whole reason **Y2K** bug started.

Comment: @StewartLancaster there only exists `YYYY-MM-DD` according to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This date format is the only one that cannot be misunderstood in international communication (https://xkcd.com/1179/). The format `YYYY-DD-MM` does not exist also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254014/are-there-locales-or-common-programs-that-use-yyyy-dd-mm-as-the-date-format

Comment: Date is a reserved word in Oracle or is it `"date"`?

Comment: I changed the date format to YYYY-MM-DD in both places and this worked - thank you so much for your swift response - i dont understand why is wasnt working with '10-MAY-20' as this is the required format in Oracle SQL developer and this works with a single date - but i am not complaining as this works - thanks again

Comment: @StewartLancaster checkout Lalit's answer below too. He explained some more.

Comment: @StewartLancaster But that's not the solution that I suggested, it is still a string unless you use the DATE function. Else Oracle will enforce an implicit data type converion from string to date. It might just work now, but it will definitely break later.

Answer (score 1):

> where  date > '10-MAY-20'  And date < '13-MAY-20'

`'10-MAY-20'` is not a date, it is a string. A date doesn't have any format, based on your locale-specific NLS settings it is displayed in a human readable format using `TO_CHAR` and proper format mask.

Also, you should avoid using two digit `YY` representation for year, it's the whole reason **Y2K** bug started. Always use `YYYY` format.

To convert a string into date:

Use `TO_DATE` and appropriate format mask:

```
where  date_col > TO_DATE('10-MAY-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')  
and    date_col < TO_DATE('13-MAY-2020', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Or, use `ANSI date literal` which uses fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

```
where  date_col > DATE '2020-05-10' and date < DATE '2020-05-13'
```

Another thing, `DATE` is an Oracle reserved word, you can see the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm). Perhaps, you are using **quoted identifier** `"date"` i.e. using double-quotation marks around the reserved word.

> i dont understand why is wasnt working with '10-MAY-20' as this is the required format in Oracle SQL developer

That's probably because your NLS settings of SQL Developer is set to `'DD-MON-YY'`, so when you pass the date in that format it doesn an implicit conversion to date. However, if you change the format it won't work:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

Comment: I would say a general and big recommendation if you work with computers is: Make sure **the only date format you ever use** is `YYYY-MM-DD` as this is the only format that is the same all around the world and even computers cannot misunderstood. If you need to use another localized format use it **for displaying purpose only**. If you follow this rule your life is much easier.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Well, the fact that Oracle is older than the ISO standard, these Oracle specific syntax exist. But, it is recommended to use the globally accepted standards.

Comment: Well, true. I should have been more precise and should have said "whenever you can, switch to `YYYY-MM-DD`" :)

Answer (score 0):

A date is not a string, and if you deal with strings that represent a date, it's up to the driver or to the database to interpret this as a date. Oracle expect a `TO_DATE`-function, for SQL server you can write it without function - if you use the right format. For other databases it might be different.

I always advocate for using `ADODB.Parameter` to pass parameters. This means slightly more code, but no more hassle with parameter formatting (true also for strings, floating numbers etc) and protection against SQL injection. You need to create an `ADODB.Command` object plus one `ADODB.Parameter` per parameter that you pass to the database. In the query, you replace the parameter value simply by a `?`

```
dim d1 as Date, d2 as Date    
d1 = CDate("2020-05-10")   ' Control of the date is completely in your hand.
d2 = CDate("2020-05-13")

StrQuery = "select  ref, date from records  where  date > ? And date < ?"
' Create command
Dim cmd as New ADODB.Command
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandText = StrQuery 

' Create 2 parameter of type Date and pass the date values
Dim param as ADODB.Parameter
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("p1", adDate, adParamInput, , d1)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("p2", adDate, adParamInput, , d2)
cmd.Parameters.Append param

Set rst = cmd.Execute
```